# Maven war plugin archiveClasses but exclude a package

Tags: java, maven, jar, war, maven-war-plugin

My maven project contains two src packages and several dependencies.
I packaged it as a war and included al dependencies like libs in `WEB-INF/libs`.

Now I need to include inside a jar all compiled project classes from `com.path.to.package.a`, but I also need to exclude compiled classes contained in `com.path.to.package.b`.

I know I can use the `<archiveClasses>` option like:

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This puts correctly the jar project inside the libs, but obviously it keeps all .class files.

I tried to perform the exclusion with some options like `<packagingExcludes>` or `<warSourceExcludes>`, but no luck with those.

Is there any option I can use paired with `<archiveClasses>` in order to exclude form the jar what i need?

Comment: where are located source class from package com.path.to.package.b ?

Comment: Why would you like to exclude class from being packged? Does not make sense? What kind of classes are those you would like to exclude?

Comment: Have you tried using <excludes><exclude>com.path.to.package.b</exclude></excludes> under <config> tag? However it sounds a better idea to separate the packages in different modules

Comment: @davidhxxx into the package path

Comment: @khmarbaise it does. It's a project with several dependencies and amog others one is a spring project and one is a gwt project. From gwt i need only the *.js produced, not classes cause they're used only to build the client side. Therefore I need to include classes only for the "server" part and exclude all the others.

Comment: @MarcoA.Hernandez tryed but i think i cannot use it for the maven-war-plugin. Correct one would be warSourceExcludes but it doen't fits to my need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seams there isn't yet a solution like the one I was looking for, I ended up with the quick and dirty following one:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>delete-unused-classes</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <delete includeemptydirs="true">
                        <fileset dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}/com/path/to/pachage/a" />
                    </delete>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Doing this way the unwanted classes are deleted before they are packaged from the `<archiveClasses>` and they do not appear inside the jar lib.